# Error running correlation analysis

Tags: r

I am trying to use R to run a correlation analysis using `Hmisc::rcorr` to find the Pearson coefficent. However, I need help understanding the error message. Can someone help out this R newbie?

This is the code I am using

```
library(Hmisc)
rcorr(Rintro_Chapter4_June_12$age, Rintro_Chapter4_June_12$credit.score, type = "pearson")
```

This is the error message I get.

```
Error in rcorr(Rintro_Chapter4_June_12$age, Rintro_Chapter4_June_12$credit.score,:
   unused arguments (Rintro_Chapter4_June_12$credit.score, type = "pearson")
```

Thank you.

Luis

Comment: `rcorr()` expects a matrix as input, while you are giving two vectors. [?rcorr](http://svitsrv25.epfl.ch/R-doc/library/Hmisc/html/rcorr.html)

Comment: Thank you, Bea, do you know how I can fix this error? The instructor used the same code and data set to run the correlation analysis and did not come up with an error.

Comment: Try `rcorr(cbind(Rintro_Chapter4_June_12$age, Rintro_Chapter4_June_12$credit.score), type = "pearson")`